# Docker entrypoint always returns permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run my web app (developed with Ruby on Rails) into a docker container and I have followings dockerfile :

```
FROM ruby:3.0.1-alpine


ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.0.2

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
      binutils-gold \
      build-base \
      curl \
      file \
      g++ \
      gcc \
      git \
      less \
      libstdc++ \
      libffi-dev \
      libc-dev \
      linux-headers \
      libxml2-dev \
      libxslt-dev \
      libgcrypt-dev \
      make \
      netcat-openbsd \
      nodejs \
      openssl \
      pkgconfig \
      postgresql-dev \
      #python \
      tzdata \
      yarn

RUN gem install bundler -v "$(grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH" Gemfile.lock | tail -n 1)"

RUN gem update --system

WORKDIR /app

# COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
COPY Gemfile ./

# RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries

RUN bundle check || bundle install

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --check-files

COPY . ./.

# RUN [ "chown", "$USER", "./entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
RUN ["chmod", "-R", "+x", "entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

with the following docker-compose file :

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development

  database:
    image: postgres:12.1
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.7

  sidekiq:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - app
      - database
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
    entrypoint: ./entrypoints/sidekiq-entrypoint.sh

volumes:
  gem_cache:
  db_data:
  node_modules:
```

My problem is when the "entrypoint" is triggered at the image starting point, I always get `app_1       | /bin/sh: can't open 'entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh': Permission denied`.

As you can see, I change the file's rights into my docker build to be able to execute it but this not solve my issue...

I've searched on the internet about this issue and for all post I saw, the `chmod` has fixed this kind of problem, so, after about 2h of "intense" web-search, I need your help ^^

Note :
The docker-entrypoint.sh file only contains :

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Br

Edit : there is the same problem with the `sidekiq-entrypoint.sh` specified in the `docker-compose` file.

Comment: The `volumes:` block overwrites the image's `/app` directory with content from the host; the `RUN chmod` command is hidden by the volume mount.

Comment: @DavidMaze tanks for your help, this fix a part of my issue. I need to fix a problem with my bundler and all will be functional :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

## BUG: Reset entrypoint to override base image.

ENTRYPOINT []

CMD entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh

Or even better try just start the server. Just to see if not running the script works

CMD bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions but there are no changes... Same error message :/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use `RUN ["chmod", "-R", "+x", "./entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]` instead of `RUN ["chmod", "-R", "+x", "entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]` and let us know.